# Parameter format not correct

Tags: flutter, error-handling, compiler-errors, runtime-error, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter and on running my pre-build application I face the below issue. Please help me to grow more in flutter.

Error Displayed on Console:

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Parameter format not correct -

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugManifest' (type 'ProcessMultiApkApplicationManifest').

> File 'D:\My Learnings For Certification\Flutter Certification Journey\Test Apps\tutorial_udemy_test_app\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\out\AndroidManifest.xml' specified for property 'mainMergedManifest' does not exist.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 48s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I was expecting my app to run normally which got failed.